# How to set the firefox binary in Serenity (previous to geckodriver)?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, junit, serenity-bdd

I'm using the serenity 1.1.42 version and I would like to run my test cases in different versions of Firefox. To do that, I try to set where is the Firefox binary file, because I'm using Mac OS, but serenity always starts with the default installed version on mi computer, the last.

What I have tried? I put into the `serenity.properties` file this different combinations:

```
webdriver.firefox.driver=/Users/myuser/Applications/Firefox55.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

In other execution:

```
webdriver.firefox.preferences="firefox.binary=/Users/myuser/Applications/Firefox55.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin"
```

In other execution:

```
webdriver.driver=/Users/myuser/Applications/Firefox55.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

In one more execution:

```
webdriver.firefox.bin=/Users/myuser/Applications/Firefox55.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

But no one of this configurations worked for me. How should I configure the `serenity.properties` file to run my own version of Firefox?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve how to pass the Firefox binary. I should pass as argument in the execution:

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/Users/myUser/Applications/Firefox44.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

But, two things to have in mind:

1. It is important not used with geckodriver, because selenium 3.0, or higher, cannot work with old Firefox versions.
2. I cannot set this property from the serenity.properties. It is ignored.

[image]